# Preiss' theorem on Riemannian manifolds

Tags: riemannian-geometry, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

This may be a silly question as it seems one of the several Euclidean results in that carry over to Riemannian manifolds by passing in coordinates, but I suspect that the issue is subtler, and I am not an expert in geometric measure theory, so I'd rather ask.

The question is: does an analogue of Preiss' theorem on rectifiability hold for Riemannian manifolds? In other words, is the following statement true:

> Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold. Let $E \subset M$ be a Borel set
> with positive and finite $k$-dimensional Hausdorff measure, where $k >0$.
> Assume that the $k$-dimensional density  $$ 0<\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\mathcal{H}^k(E\cap B(x,r))}{r^k}<+\infty \qquad (\star) $$ (existence is one of the requirements) for
> $\mathcal{H}^k$-a.e. $x \in E$. Then $k$ is an integer, and $E$ is
> rectifiable, i.e. it can be covered up to a $\mathcal{H}^k$-null set
> by $C^1$ $k$-dimensional submanifolds.

Here, I stress, $\mathcal{H}^k$ is the $k$-dimensional Hausdorff measure associated with the Riemannian metric structure, and $B(x,r)$ is the Riemannian ball.

The Euclidean version of the statement is well-known, cf for example

*De Lellis, Camillo*, [**Rectifiable sets, densities and tangent measures**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4171/044), Zurich Lectures in Advanced Mathematics. Zürich: European Mathematical Society (EMS) (ISBN 978-3-03719-044-9/pbk). vi, 126 p. (2008). [ZBL1183.28006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1183.28006).

One then needs to show that if $(\star)$ holds then it implies its Euclidean counterpart for (almost) all points in charts. It is immediate to show that for any $x\in E$ where $(\star)$ holds, there exists a (normal) coordinate chart around $x$ such that the Euclidean counterpart of $(\star)$ holds at $x$, but what about other close points in the neighborhood?

Notice that, in a neighborhood of a given point $x$, and for any fixed coordinate chart $U$ around $x \in E$, the Riemannian distance is bi-Lipschitz equivalent to the Euclidean distance in these charts:

$$
c |y-z| \leq d(y,z) \leq C |y-z|, \qquad y,z \in U
$$

for some $c,C>0$, depending on $U$. This only yields that

$$
0<\liminf_{r\to 0} \frac{\mathcal{H}^k_{\mathbb{R}^n}(E\cap B_{\mathbb{R}^n}(x,r))}{r^k} \leq \limsup_{r\to 0} \frac{\mathcal{H}^k_{\mathbb{R}^n}(E\cap B_{\mathbb{R}^n}(x,r))}{r^k} < +\infty,
$$

where $_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ means that we are considering the corresponding objects using the Euclidean coordinate structure. This of course does not prove the existence of the density in charts, and we cannot invoke Preiss' Euclidean result on $U$.

**---- UPDATE AFTER COMMENTS ----**

Of course one can choose coordinates such that the constants $c,C$ in the above bi-Lipschitz embedding in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are arbitrarily close to $1$. In this way one can show that the limsup and the liminf of the density in those local coordinates are very close, and then use the stronger version of Preiss' theorem, which says that there exists a constant $c(n,k)>1$ such that if
$$
0< \limsup_{r\to 0} \frac{\mathcal{H}^k_{\mathbb{R}^n}(E\cap B_{\mathbb{R}^n}(x,r))}{r^k} \leq c(k,n) \liminf_{r\to 0} \frac{\mathcal{H}^k_{\mathbb{R}^n}(E\cap B_{\mathbb{R}^n}(x,r))}{r^k} < \infty
$$
for $\mathcal{H}^k_{\mathbb{R}^n}$-almost every $x$, then $E$ is $k$-rectifiable (even if the density in coordinates a priori might not exist). However, I would rather avoid using this rather complex quantitative result, and I do think that the density in local coordinates exists provided that $(\star)$ holds.

Comment: I'm hardly an expert on this, but I believe there is a stronger quantitative version of Preiss's theorem where the same result holds as long as the upper density ratio is controlled by a universal constant (depending on $k$ and $n$ only) times the lower density ratio.  This should suffice on sufficiently small balls (where one can take $c$ and $C$ as close to $1$ as you like).  This is Theorem 1.2 in De Lellis's book (though he does not prove it).

Comment: I am aware of the quantitative version of Preiss' theorem. I agree that this might be a strategy, but I wonder whether one really needs this rather hard quantitative result to prove the weaker version of the statement on Riemannian manifolds. I hope that some expert might shed some light on this. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: I see.  Another approach would be to use the Nash embedding theorem and the fact that small intrinic balls are asymptotically the same as the interesction of small extrinsic balls with the embedding.  Of course, this is using another big hammer;

Comment: Just a thought: is it not true that given any compact subset $K \subset M$ and any $\delta > 0$ there is $\rho > 0$ so that around every point $p \in K$, there is a coordinate chart in $B_\rho(p)$ that is $(1+\delta)$-bi-Lipschitz? Perhaps this needs a rescaling of the metrics by $\rho$, but that shouldn't be an issue when working with densities, no?

Comment: Couldn’t you use stronger properties of the Riemannian metric beyond bilipschitz to Euclidean space?

Comment: @Lee Moos, this is precisely the first comment by RBega2 (in normal coordinates): go in normal coordinates where c/C can be made close as we wish to 1 in a very small ball around x, and use the stronger quantitative version of Preiss' result.

Comment: @daene yang: could you please elaborate? Even using normal coordinates I am not able to prove that the density (in charts) exists in a given small neighborhood of any given point.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part of RBega2's comment. I think the point stands, however. Unless I am missing something, letting $\delta \to 0$ (and $\rho \to 0$) you should find that not only are the liminf and limsup arbitrarily close, but in fact they agree.

Comment: At a given point, for a fixed charts yes. But for all points in a small coordinate chart, I do not see how. (Notice that a chart should be fixed, and then existence of density should be proven for a.e point in that chart).

Comment: I am not sure I understand what the concern is. Using the $(1+\delta)$-bi-Lipschitz equivalence, you find that for all $p \in K$, $\Theta^*(E,p) \leq (1 + \epsilon) \Theta_{*}(E,p)$, where $\epsilon \to 0$ as $\delta \to 0$. The densities do not depend on $\rho$, so you can let this tend to zero to get that they agree. Note also that there is a typo in the stronger version of Preiss' theorem that you state: you need to swap the upper and lower densities.

Comment: The densities do not depend on rho, but for each p you are choosing a different chart to compute the density, so that you are not proving that the density exists for all point on a given chart. Statement fixed thanks.

Comment: I would add that, if such an estimate holds, it's gotta be in the literature somewhere, i would look at papers written by De Lellis and his co-authors as well as Cheeger and his co-authors (like Tian, Naber, Colding).